Confusion between trigonal and hexagonal systems
I'm studying space groups.
It's quite clear (I think) why trigonal and hexagonal systems collapse in the same primitive Bravais lattice, while are different when we introduce non-primitive unit cells, with the rhombohedral primitive cell attributable only to a trigonal system.
The confusion arise in assigning crystallographic point groups to one or another, starting from the Cn point group and adding systematically more symmetry elements without going out from the current system.
For example, why C3h is a point group for hexagonal systems?
I'm searching a file rouge between the classes of each of the two systems, in case also using stereographic projection.
